# Queueable not restoring state for execute() in unit test

Tags: queueable-interface

I have a Queueable implementation that is working fine, but fails when I try to test it.  It seems that when unit testing the state is not properly being restored during the `execute` method.

**Test Method**

```
...
Test.startTest();
UsesChainable uc = new UsesChainable();
uc.createChain();
Test.stopTest();
...
```

**Intermediate class**

```
public class UsesChainable{
   public void createChain(){
     ...
     Chainable ch = new Chainable(chainActions);
     System.debug(ch.currentLink);  //this outputs a non-null value!
     System.enqueueJob(ch);
   }
}
```

**Queuable Class**

```
public class Chainable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{
  public ChainableLink currentLink;
  ...

 public void execute(QueueableContext context){
        System.debug(currentLink); //outputs NULL!
        ...
```

Looking at the logs, nothing else is happening between when I call `System.enqueueJob` and when the `execute` method runs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why, but this works if I enqueue the chain directly from the test method instead of from my "Intermediate" class:

**Test Method**

```
...
Test.startTest();
UsesChainable uc = new UsesChainable();
Chainable ch = uc.createChain();
System.enqueueJob(ch);
Test.stopTest();
...
```

**Intermediate class**

```
public class UsesChainable{
   public Chainable createChain(){
     ...
     return new Chainable(chainActions);    
   }
}
```

Must have something to do with how salesforce stores serialization data between test contexts.

Now if I can just figure out how to get it to play nice with `HttpCalloutMock`...

Comment: Can you use implement Database.Stateful and try it out

Comment: @SantanuBoral if you add `Database.Stateful` to a Queueable it throws an exception: `System.AsyncException: Queueable cannot be implemented with other system interfaces`

Comment: That's quite surprising. You can certainly implement `Database.AllowsCallouts` as a second system interface...

Comment: @AdrianLarson Queueable is "stateful" by default.  And yes, it does let you use the `Database.AllowsCallouts` with `Queueable`.  Seems like the error message should say:  `Queueable cannot be implemented with Database.Stateful`